# How can I update and replicate one column from one table to another column from another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, jobs, procedures, replicate

I need to replicate one column (`TYPE`) from one table (`CUTOMER`) to another column (`UNDEF000`) from table (`ORDERS`), by this way everytime when someone update column(`TYPE`) to be automaticaly replicated on (`UNDEF000`), Table `CUSTOMER` and `ORDERS` are linked by column (`PRE_ORDERCODE`).

First I try to fill `UNDEF000` from `TYPE`:

```
UPDATE ORDERS 
JOIN CUSTOMER
SET ORDERS.UNDEF000=CUSTOMER.TYPE
WHERE ORDERS.PRE_ORDERCODE= CUSTOMER.PRE_ORDERCODE;
```

not function :(

```
UPDATE ORDERS
SET ORDERS.UNDEF000= CUSTOMER.TYPE
FROM CUSTOMER CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN ORDERS ORDERS
ON CUSTOMER.PRE_ORDERCODE= ORDERS.PRE_ORDERCODE
```

Can you please help me with this two problems?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch15.htm

Comment: are you looking to write a trigger? once when a field is updated the trigger will act upon?

Comment: yes , i would like to write a trigger but first i think i need to have both column with the same information.

Answer (score 0):

I think your update should be like:

```
UPDATE ORDERS O SET O.UNDEF000= (
SELECT CUSTOMER.TYPE FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE CUSTOMER.PRE_ORDERCODE = O.PRE_ORDERCODE);
```

Trigger code:

```
create or replace trigger after_update_customer after update on
customer for each row
declare

begin
update orders set UNDEF000 = :new.type 
where pre_ordercode = :new.pre_ordercode;
end;
```

Comment: Is FUnction with DISTINCT because i have more records in CUSTOMER than ORDERS , Thank you very much                                                UPDATE ORDERS O SET O.UNDEF000= (
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER.TYPE FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER.PRE_ORDERCODE= CUSTOMER.PRE_ORDERCODE)                                                                                                                                                                              Thank you very much Aramillo

Comment: Now i must create a trigger or procedures ? In order to have the same data after someone update TYPE from CUSTOMER ? thx

Comment: Yes, you need a trigger. take a look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php)

Comment: thank you very much again ,  with this trigger everytime when i make an upddate on TYPE on specfic row this trigger updates all data from UNDEF000 , can you please help :(

Comment: Hi, you are right, i forgot put where condition. :)

Comment: :((( is the same , perhaps i must put where customer.pre_ordercode=orders.pre_ordercode?

Comment: Yes you are right. Is with primary key column. check now

Comment: is not function :(( i receive the same result